# How do I create the .Xauthority file?

Tags: xorg

I don't have a .Xauthority file in my home folder. I want to create it, please tell me the steps to do so in ubuntu 10.10.

Thank You!

Comment: Maybe it would help, if you tell us why you want/need to create this file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ubuntu 10.10 there's no longer a `~/.Xauthority` file. Instead you'll find the equivalent in

`/var/run/gdm/auth-for-<USER>-<RANDOM_CHARACTERS>/database`

which will be re-created with new random characters on every session start. You can get its name via the `$XAUTHORITY` environment variable.

If you need a `~/.Xauthority` file to be present, I guess you can simply create a symbolic link to `$AUTHORITY` on every session start:

1. Open `System > Preferences > Startup Applications`
2. Click on `Add` :

   - Name: `Xauthority`
   - Command: `/bin/bash -c 'ln -s -f "$XAUTHORITY" ~/.Xauthority'`
   - Comment: `Creates a symbolic link from ~/.Xauthority to $XAUTHORITY`

   and add the entry by clicking on `Add`.
3. Now every time you log in, it should create the link to the current authority file.

Comment: On my 10.10, there is no `~/.Xauthority` by default.

Comment: @loevborg: Thanks, I totally missed that. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys problem is solved, actually problem was setting the wrong ENV variable in the script for $DISPLAY

Comment: On my 12.04, there's still an `~./Xauthority` file...

Comment: I'm unsure if this answer is correct anymore. I can say that as of April 2018 my `Ubuntu 16.04` still expects to have an `~./Xauthority` file

Answer (score 4):

(there indeed appears to be .Xauthority files in Ubuntu 14.10, so I don't know, per the accepted answer, if they went away and came back?)

Probably solved a long time ago but for completeness, when you ssh to a remote system, use:

```
ssh -X user@remote
```

You will get a complaint that the .Xauthority file did not exist and also find it was just created. This is dependent some settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
X11Forwarding yes 
X11DisplayOffset 10 
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Refer to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1863739 where I was able to confirm my own experience with this errant error.

While you are checking / updating /etc/ssh/sshd_config make sure root login is disallowed, just a good practice:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```