# Cannot open browser or update system because because of lack of permissions after using "Stacer" to clear browser cache

Tags: permissions, sudo, filesystem, system

I used the app Stacer to free some disk space by removing Opera's and Chrome's cache, but I think it did something else because after that I've been having a lot of problems. Most notably, I cannot open Opera anymore. Upon clicking the launcher I get an error pop up saying I lack privileges to open the profile file. Chrome won't even throw an error, it simply doesn't launch.

The first time I rebooted the system after the cache clearing, I was met with a command prompt and had to do `fsck /dev/sda4` manually because there were many errors in the system. After fixing everything it did boot, but the permissions issues began. After that, I rebooted many times over the day and sometimes it wouldn't get to the login screen, and other times it would.

Entering `ls -l .Xauthority` in the terminal returns *ls: cannot access '.Xauthority: No such file or directory*

Trying to perform a system update with `sudo apt get && sudo apt upgrade` returns a lot of "read only" issues (shortened it because it was too long for the post).

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Atteint:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                 
Err:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg                 
  Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
Atteint:4 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                          
0% [4 InRelease gpgv 4.487 B] [Connexion à ar.archive.ubuntu.com (200.236.31.4Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.skype.com_deb_dErr:4 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:5 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                 
0% [5 InRelease gpgv 2.842 B] [Connexion à ar.archive.ubuntu.com (200.236.31.4Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.coErr:5 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                     
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Ign:7 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                      
Atteint:8 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                 
Atteint:9 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                    
0% [8 InRelease gpgv 247 kB] [Attente des fichiers d'en-tête] [Attente des ficCouldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ar.archive.ubuntu.coErr:8 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Err:10 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release.gpg                   
  Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release               
  Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_Release - open (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement) [IP : 91.189.91.26 80]
Atteint:12 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                      
0% [12 InRelease gpgv 3.302 B] [Attente des fichiers d'en-tête] [Connexion à Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.coErr:12 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                          
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Ign:13 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease            
Réception de:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease [2.562 B]
Ign:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                  
Atteint:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
0% [15 InRelease gpgv 23,8 kB] [Attente des fichiers d'en-tête] [Connexion à Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gnoErr:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Ign:16 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease          
Atteint:17 https://deb.opera.com/opera-beta stable InRelease                   
0% [17 InRelease gpgv 2.592 B] [Connexion à ar.archive.ubuntu.com (200.236.31.Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.opera.com_opera-Err:17 https://deb.opera.com/opera-beta stable InRelease                       
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Réception de:18 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Release [1.694 B] 
Err:18 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Release                    
  Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.sublimetext.com_apt_stable_Release - open (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
Atteint:19 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                 
0% [19 InRelease gpgv 2.592 B] [Attente des fichiers d'en-tête] [Attente des fCouldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.opera.com_opera-Err:19 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                     
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu xenial InRelease
0% [20 InRelease gpgv 18,1 kB] [Attente des fichiers d'en-tête] [Connexion à Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_hanErr:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:21 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
0% [21 InRelease gpgv 4.701 B] [Attente des fichiers d'en-tête] [Connexion à Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.winehq.org_wine-buErr:22 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release              
  Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_Release - open (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement) [IP : 200.236.31.4 80]
Err:21 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
0% [23 InRelease gpgv 17,5 kB] [Attente des fichiers d'en-tête] [Connexion à Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_inkErr:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Err:24 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release            
  Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_Release - open (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement) [IP : 200.236.31.4 80]
Atteint:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
0% [25 InRelease gpgv 18,1 kB] [Connexion à ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_kdeErr:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-5-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
0% [26 InRelease gpgv 23,8 kB] [Connexion à ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_libErr:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-5-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu xenial InRelease
0% [27 InRelease gpgv 18,0 kB] [Connexion à ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_obsErr:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease
0% [28 InRelease gpgv 17,5 kB] [Connexion à ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ottErr:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ozmartian/apps/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
0% [29 InRelease gpgv 18,0 kB] [Connexion à ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ozmErr:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ozmartian/apps/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stk/dev/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
0% [30 InRelease gpgv 23,8 kB] [Connexion à ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_stkErr:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stk/dev/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu xenial InRelease
0% [31 InRelease gpgv 18,0 kB] [Connexion à ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_thoErr:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu xenial InRelease      
0% [32 InRelease gpgv 17,5 kB] [Connexion à ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_tisErr:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu xenial InRelease
0% [33 InRelease gpgv 23,8 kB] [Connexion à ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuErr:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Atteint:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/haguichi/ubuntu xenial InRelease
0% [34 InRelease gpgv 17,5 kB]Couldn't create tempfiles for splitting up /var/liErr:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/haguichi/ubuntu xenial InReleaseease
  Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
Lecture des listes de paquets... Erreur !
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Verrou non utilisé pour le fichier /var/lib/apt/lists/lock en lecture seule
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.74Ktao - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.ejhf3l - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.QaQ0Vj - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.sluMOh - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.n4cyHf - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.2uWjAd - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.sNI5sb - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.HtARl9 - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.NYsDe7 - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.ANpp74 - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.KArb02 - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.8auXS0 - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.mIzJLY - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.ikKvEW - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.fjWhxU - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.04c4pS - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.5HuQiQ - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.H1OCbO - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.v8dp4L - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.fHEbXJ - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.b79XPH - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.srIKIF - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.glhxBD - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.oxVjuB - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.TcB6mz - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.CSlTfx - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release.gpg - pkgAcqMetaSig (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.skype.com_deb_dists_stable_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.skype.com_deb_dists_stable_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.skype.com_deb_dists_stable_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.skype.com_deb_dists_stable_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.skype.com_deb_dists_stable_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease: Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.vivaldi.com_stable_deb_dists_stable_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.vivaldi.com_stable_deb_dists_stable_Release - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.vivaldi.com_stable_deb_dists_stable_Release.gpg - pkgAcqMetaSig (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.vivaldi.com_stable_deb_dists_stable_Release failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.vivaldi.com_stable_deb_dists_stable_Release failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.vivaldi.com_stable_deb_dists_stable_Release failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.vivaldi.com_stable_deb_dists_stable_Release failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release: Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_Release - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.sublimetext.com_apt_stable_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_gnome3-team_gnome3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gnome3-team_gnome3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gnome3-team_gnome3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gnome3-team_gnome3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gnome3-team_gnome3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_haguichi_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_haguichi_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/haguichi/ubuntu xenial InRelease: Impossible d'exécuter « apt-key » pour contrôler la signature (veuillez vérifier si gnupg est installé).
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - mkstemp (30: Système de fichiers accessible en lecture seulement)
E: Les listes de paquets ou le fichier « status » ne peuvent être analysés ou lus.
```

OS: Ubuntu Gnome 16.04LTS 64 bits

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using ? What diagnostic software did you run ? and what errors are you getting ? I agree, it must be more than clearing the cache.

Comment: I added the system info in the original question. I used "Stacer" to clear the browser cache. The errors I get are explained in the question. Thanks for replying.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/21923/how-do-i-create-the-xauthority-file and https://askubuntu.com/questions/124038/xauthority-required-but-missing

Comment: Thanks. I've checked the first post where they explain where the xauthority equivalent is located in newer releases. However, I cannot check the directory because I cannot open nautilus (clicking the launcher does nothing) and trying to cd with the terminal will only get me to `/var/run/gdm3` (gdm alone didn't exist) and I get stuck there because I don't have permissions to go any further. It says "cannot open directory - permission denied"

Comment: My guess is you ran something as root , probably a graphical application or gksu or who knows, and changed the permission of your home directory. Open a terminal and run `sudo chown -R your_user:your_user /home/your_user`

Comment: Because I was having trouble with linux, I rebooted into windows yesterday and it gave me a warning to reboot and check the HDD because it might have errors.. so I think it is possible that the HDD damaged. I started making a backup to reinstall everything and Linux suddenly was working fine. I'm still not sure what the real problem is, but I'm formatting. If I have problems after that, it's most likely a faulty drive. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Comment: If you think your hard drive is faulty backups are the place to start. You can also run smartmontools - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools . In my experience, failing drives limp along until they die with little to no warning.

Comment: I wiped the drive and windows installed fine in the first 100gb, however ubuntu didn't want to install in the next partition. Will have to replace the hard drive. Thanks for your help. Do I mark this as closed even though it wasn't "answered"?