# I killed Xorg. after reboot, gdm3 freezes

Tags: 18.04, xorg, gdm

I killed xorg process and now, after rebooting, the login screen is frozen.
I tried booting into recovery mode but I couldn't restart xorg.

Pardon my minimal understanding of xorg and what it does.

Events:
I used pc -C Xorg to find the xrog processes.
Then killed one of them.
gdm3 crashed and the computer froze.
rebooted.
gdm3 login screen is frozen.
booted into recovery mode and tried the following:
1. systemctl restart gdm3
2. init 3
3. systemctl restart display-manager

Comment: Can you please provide details of what you actually did.  I can't see how a `kill` command could cause a change in `gdm3` but it's possibly you are talking about a different command to the `kill` I'm thinking of.  Use `history` to view your command history for exact details if you used commands; it's likely the `kill` and `gdm3` are not related.

Comment: The thing is, I killed a process and then the display manager crashed. after rebooting, the display manager is frozen

Answer (score 0):

In fact `startx` or `xinit` would start the xorg server but if you still have problems regarding the login screen,you can try sddm.
`sudo apt install sddm`
and during the installation, change the default display manager to sddm.
[Display manager configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xk9e.png)

Comment: Ok, so basically, if nothing is working, change the display manager?

Comment: I get an error message when executing startx-> /root/.Xauthority doesnt exists

Comment: "Changing the display manager":You can mess around with that for hours and hours but trying an alternative would be a good solution as it saves you a ton of time.Recently I wanted to change the color of oxygen icon theme in KDE so I decided to change some symlinks and configurations and everything in the settings looked fine but the actual icons were still the same.I even deleted that icons but I didn't know where those strange things came from.I mean sometimes picking an alternative and forgetting about past can be the solution.

Comment: Also take a look at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124038/xauthority-required-but-missing) for that problem.

Comment: Try starting xorg  as a user other than root(If you have.)

Comment: sudo group user would work?

Comment: Ok, after trying tons of things, I just followed your advice and installed lightdm

Comment: Running commands as a sudo group user still uses your home directory as ~/  .  So must work fine.