# How to create .Xauthority file in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04

Tags: login, 17.04, vnc

Stressing ***17.04***.

I want to use VNC Connect to I can use my computer from my phone. However, I do not have a `.Xauthority` file. I saw the other question, "[How do I create the `.Xauthority` file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21923/690724)" and it is for Ubuntu 10.10.

I'm stressing the difference between this question and that question because this isn't a dupe question; the `.Xauthority` file is bound to be vastly different from 7 years ago.

I have the `.ICEauthority` file but no `.Xauthority` file. I don't know what other information I need to provide, but I will if I can.

Comment: AFAIK it's generated by default. If I delete it and restart X, it gets regenerated.

Comment: @AndroidDev What is X?

Comment: X11 is the "kernel" of the UI if you will.

Comment: @AndroidDev So how do I restart X11?

Comment: I usually go to `tty1` and do `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: @AndroidDev What's `tty1`?

Comment: It's one of many virtual terminals. You can access it by pressing `CTRL+ALT+F1`. And you can get back to the GUI by switching to `tty7`, with `CTRL+ALT+F7`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63681/discussion-between-amolith-and-android-dev).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the GNOME display manager `gdm3` does not use `~/.Xauthority` so this may require an application-specific answer for VNC Connect. As the manual page says, "Upon session startup, GDM sets the XAUTHORITY environment variable to a session-specific file in `/var/run/gdm3`. Applications and scripts that assume this file is set to `~/.Xauthority` will not work. To access the display you need both `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` variables."

I wound up on this page because the missing `.Xauthority` issue also arises when trying to run graphical applications as root on Wayland (Ubuntu GNOME 17.10). As described at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Running_X_apps_as_root, the fallback X server won't work when running programs as root, but you can fix this by first running `xhost +local:`. Possibly a similar approach will address the VNC Connect issue.