# No Xhauthority file

Tags: 17.10, postgresql

I am a new Ubuntu and Linux user coming from windows and have a problem installing Postgres on Ubuntu 17.10.

(By the way I have no clue what Wayland is)

well I tried to follow this link: [Linux downloads (Ubuntu) | PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) coupled with this tut : [Install PostgreSQL 10 on Ubuntu | Linux Hint](https://linuxhint.com/install-postgresql-10-on-ubuntu/)

I am stuck when I want to edit /etc/apt/sources.list as I can open it and edit it with text editor but cannot save it. I can't either create a new file inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

It says I don't have the rights.

Then in console I typed:

```
ls -la ~/.Xauthority
```

which returns :

> ls: cannot access '/home/maxence/.Xauthority': No such file or
>   directory

Then I stumbled on this thread [How do I create the .Xauthority file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21923/how-do-i-create-the-xauthority-file) that says we have to create a kind of link poiting to the Xauthority file that resides somewhere else.

But again I am stuck on this bit :

> 1. Open System > Preferences > Startup Applications

Where do I go to open system ??

Comment: How do you edit /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Comment: Just run `sudo apt-get install postgresql` in a console to install postgresql. The basic instructions for ubuntu are at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Not sure why I stumbled on this tutorial. It is now installed

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1 Editing configuration files

Do you use `sudo` in front of your text editor when you try to edit /etc/apt/sources.list ?

This is required to edit any file inside the `/etc/` directory.

For example `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

For more information on `sudo` and access right on Linux, you can see  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

### Question 2 .Xauthority

Are you on a Ubuntu server distribution (console only) or with a graphical interface ?

### Question 3 Access to preferences

If you're on a standard Ubuntu edition (with Unity as GUI), preferences are the gear icon ⚙ in the sidebar.

Comment: Hi flow, 1) I did tried Sudo nano but my file was then open inside the terminal which I thought was not very convenient and wasn't sure how to edit in there.  Then I just opened text editor and edited. 2) I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 which Gnome I think. I do have a user interface. 3) I don't see the gear icon. Yet I clicked on the word 'activities' on the top bar and typed 'startup..' which pulled a startup application icon. Also I have installed Postgresql as per Daniel.. so all good now ... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Nice if your issue is resolved :)